# In java its not calculating correctly

Tags: java, string, integer

When trying to compute my homework from an integer to a string and then producing it correctly

basically what im trying to do for my homework is go ahead of the class, the teacher wants us to use a basic Scanner and ask the user for input, I would rather do it in textfields and a text area

so for my program I Have a textfield asking the user what the total price is which is a double

I think compute the totals into a text area  all with new lines

for some reason the way I did the conversions of taking the dollar amount and breaking it down to how many bills and coins they need is not coming out correctly here is there conversion below

```
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // This class is being made to get the formula or what needs to be done

    // leaving this as tfAnswer even though its the value of dollar
    sDollarTotal = tfAnswer.getText();
    iDollarTotal = Double.valueOf(sDollarTotal);

    // Converting Distance to integer from string
    iTen = (int) (iDollarTotal / 10);
    sTen = String.valueOf(iTen);

    // calc the five bucks dude
    iFives = (int) ((iDollarTotal - iTen * 10) / 5);  //take the int  use the modules operator

    sFive = String.valueOf(iFives);

    // take the whole number and the whole number 

    iOne = (int) (((iDollarTotal - iTen * 10 - iFives * 5)));
    sOne = String.valueOf(iOne);

    iQuarter = (int) ((iDollarTotal - iTen * 10 - iFives * 5 - iOne) / 0.25);
    sQuarter = String.valueOf(iQuarter);

    iDime = (int) ((iDollarTotal - iTen * 10 - iFives * 5 - iOne - iQuarter * 0.25) / .10);
    sDime = String.valueOf(iDime);

    iNickel = (int) ((iDollarTotal - iTen * 10 - iFives * 5 - iOne
            - iQuarter * 0.25 - iDime * .10) / .05);
    sNickel = String.valueOf(iNickel);

    iPenny = (int) ((iDollarTotal - iTen * 10 - iFives * 5 - iOne
            - iQuarter * 0.25 - iDime * .10 - iNickel * .05) / .01);
    sPenny = String.valueOf(iPenny);

    textArea.setText(sTen + " Ten Dollar Bill" + "\n" + sFive
            + " Five Dollar Bills" + "\n" + sOne + " One dollar bill \n"
            + sQuarter + " Quarters \n" + sDime + " Dimes \n" + sNickel
            + " Nickels \n" + sPenny + " Pennys \n");

}
```

Now when the user enters a number 25.46 cents it displays 
2 tens
1 five
0 ones
1 quarter
2 dimes
0 nickels
1 penny

But when the user enters 25.56 it displays

2 tens
1 five
0 ones
0 quarter
0 dimes
1 nickel
0 pennys

which is obviously not right.  I tried using the modules operator but I couldn't figure out the formula to use it correctly,   so I broke it down this way,

Can anyone tell me why when I use 25.56 it displays 0 pennies.

Comment: What do you see when you step through your code in a debugger?  That is what I would do.  BTW I would use local variables, not fields here. You don't need to call String.valueOf() at all.

Comment: You should track the total you haven't changed in a variable like iDollarTotal. It will save a bunch of writing now and in the future.

Comment: or... if you can't use a debugger, besides learning how to use it... dump your variables throughout the code and look at what everything is at certain points.  so... after calculating `iOne` and `iQuater` and everything, dump/display/whatever the value so you can see it.  and break apart some of the things... so, if the value for `iPenny` is wrong, do the calculation in sections so you can see what part of it is killing your value.  output after each section of calculation... then put it back together when you've fixed whatever.

Comment: 10 bucks says its from casting to ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you not use double at all here as it is clearly confusing you.

If you are going to use double, you should always round your results instead of rounding down.  Additionally as 0.1 and 0.01 and 0.05 cannot be represented accurately, you should avoid using them.

```
    int iPenny = (int) Math.round((iDollarTotal - iTen * 10 - iFives * 5 - iOne
            - iQuarter * 0.25 - iDime / 10.0 - iNickel / 20.0) * 100);
```

prints the correct result in this case.

---

However, I still suggest you start with.

```
long cents = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(tfAnswer.getText()) * 100);
```

after this you don't need to use any floating point.

Comment: I havent checked the debugger yet because like penguin said im not 100% sure how to do that.  But why would the double be confusing me? Isn't it just a number with decimal points or is there more too it?

Comment: And you're right with the string . value of I was converting it to text fields before untik I turned the page in the book and it said I had to do coins as well so I changed it to text area

Comment: A debugger should be the first thing you use if you have a bug, not SO.  A double is a binary floating point, i.e. it cannot represent decimals like 0.1,  0.01 or 25.56 accurately and if you don't know how to handle the representation error you will get strange problems like this.

Comment: thanks I will research the double a lot more. I did not know I didn't understand it till now.

Comment: I thought for the day; print out `new BigDecimal(0.1)` and see what you get and see if you can explain why. ;)